# Sending a pointer to a pointer by reference

Tags: c

I have been trying to send a pointer to a pointer (we can call it an array of strings, or an array of an array of chars even) to a function, by reference, because I need it to be updated. I don't want to have the function returning the pointer to a pointer (that one I got working) because I want the return to be the size of the array.

This is a working function I created for testing purposes, which returns the pointer to a pointer, and the calling method:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **populate_items() {
        char **items;
        int i;
        items = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
                *(items+i) = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        items[0] = "1234567890";
        items[1] = "2345678901";
        items[2] = "3456789012";
        return items;
}

int main(int argv, char *argc) {
        char **items;
        int i;
        items = populate_items();
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
                printf("%s\n", items[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

This is what I THINK the function and the call to the function that gets the pointer to a pointer as reference should look like, but I get a segmentation fault when trying to print items[1] or items[2]

```
#include <stdio.h>

populate_items(char ***items) {
        int i;
        *items = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
                *(items+i) = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        *items[0] = "1234567890";
        *items[1] = "2345678901";
        *items[2] = "3456789012";
}

int main(int argv, char *argc) {
        char **items;
        int i;
        populate_items(&items);
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
                printf("%s\n", items[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

In the abstraction that I created in my head, the function should be fine, but off course it's not given that I'm getting a segmentation fault. I already managed to understand how a pointer to a pointer works just fine, but I think I'm having trouble putting my head over how the pointer to a pointer to a pointer concept translates into code.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a dereference and got the precedence of `*` vs. `[]` wrong:

```
populate_items(char ***items) {
        int i;
        *items = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
                *(*items+i) = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        (*items)[0] = "1234567890";
        (*items)[1] = "2345678901";
        (*items)[2] = "3456789012";
}
```

Note, however, that the assignments

```
(*items)[0] = "1234567890";
```

etc. lose the only handle to the just allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you! Line 7 (the second malloc) has an error, but I don't need that malloc anyway, so I just took the whole for loop out. Again, thank you very much, I'll look out for precedences in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot a `*` there too. It's much easier if you use `[]`.

Comment: "Note, however, that the assignments...etc. lose the only handle to the just allocated memory." ... but this is solved if I remove the for loop with the second malloc, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you don't malloc these, there's no memory to be leaked.

Comment: the above code won't work, because in that there is no memory allocated for ***items , here he is only allocating for **items and *item .

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh `items` is the address of a `char**` in the caller, so `*items` already has a memory location. The first `malloc` stores the address of a block large enough for three `char*` there, `(*items)[i]` for `i = 0, 1, 2`. Then in the loop, each of these is assigned the address of a block large enough for 10 `char`s, that's the memory corresponding to `***items`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : you first execute your code and you well find what is wrong with your code...i executed your code it gave segmentation fault ...so we need to allocate memory for ***items to store **items address and for **items to store *items address

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh I ran it too. It doesn't segfault if you call it as it is intended, `char **passed_ptr; populate_items(&passed_ptr);`. (Of course, it leaks memory,as said.)

Answer (score -1):

you can use as below

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>


 char*** populate_items(char ***items) 
 {
      int i;
      items = (char ***) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
      for (i=0; i<3; i++)
            *(items + i) = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
      **(items + 0) = "1234567890";
      **(items + 1) = "2345678901";
      **(items + 2) = "3456789012";
      return items;
 }

 int main(int argv, char *argc) 
 {
      char **items;
      int i;
      char *** res = populate_items(&items);
      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            printf("%s\n", **(res + i));
      return 0;
 }
```